# node.js redis smembers synchronously

Tags: node.js, redis, synchronization

I wonder if it's possible to implement synchronous retrieval of smembers of redis with [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis).

```
_.each(seeds, function(subseed, key, list){

    client.smembers(subseed, function (err, replies) {
        retrieved = retrieved.concat(replies)
    })
})
client.quit();
console.log("start")
console.log(retrieved.length)
```

OUTPUT:

```
start
0
10
```

So it looks like I need somehow to get to the point when smembers finishes it's run, ot alternatively to run smembers in synchronous mode.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want to make it synchronous? 
If you want to do something after `members`, just do it in callback function.

```
var callback=function(res){
    retrived=retrieved.concat(res);
    //continue do other things
};

client.smembers("offer", function (err, replies) {
    if(!err){
        callback(replies);
    }
})
```

If you want to do something after a loop,you can try `_.after` of `underscore.js`,for example:

```
var times=10;

var arrayOfReplies=[]; //store all replies
var callback=function(){
    //do something with arrayOfReplies
}

var afterAll = _.after(times,callback); //afterAll's callback is a function which will be run after be called 10 times

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){   
    client.smembers("offer", function (err, replies) {
        if(!err){
            arrayOfReplies=arrayOfReplies.concat(replies);
            afterAll();
        }
    })
}
```

see more:http://underscorejs.org/#after

Comment: great, thank you, but what if I have a loop of async runs like on the example that I've changed, how to get control at the end of all async runs. Thank you.